# Open a GTK program as another user

Tags: command-line

As `thisuser`, I go to shell and run `$ su anotheruser`. It asks for password and then switches the user. Then I run `$ gedit anyfile`. But now instead of opening gedit, it gives error:

```
No protocol specified
(gedit:388): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :20.0
```

How do I get this running?

EDIT:

Output of `ls -l "$XAUTHORITY"` when run as `anotheruser`

```
-rw------- 1 thisuser thisuser 260 Mar 31 22:35 /home/thisuser/.Xauthority
```

Comment: Add the output of `ls -l "$XAUTHORITY"` to your question..

Answer (score 1):

For running GUI applications (e.g. gedit in your case) as another user you can use `gksudo`. I am not sure if it comes with default Ubuntu now but you can install:

```
 sudo apt-get install gksu
```

And then run like this:

```
 gksudo -u <user goes here> gedit <file goes here>
```

Comment: When I run this, I see `gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package...` is there an updated answer on how to do this? And actually, I'm not interested in running a graphical program as root, but as a different non-privileged user.